# Phpstrorm code coverage not work

Tags: php, phpstorm

Can you help me? When  create unit test class and my test is run okay, but I try to run test with code coverage the test always show 0%.

```
<?php
include 'BowlingGame.php';
class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function firstTest(){
        $a = new BowlingGame();

        $this->assertEquals(16,$a->row(16));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage requires XDebug extension which you most likely do not have installed.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/monitoring-code-coverage-for-php-applications.html